# How to find the significance of each input in determining the output of a neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have a simple neural network in Keras with 16 inputs and 1 output. I want to be able to find out which of these inputs is the most important in determining the output (i.e. varying which input would affect the output the most). How can I do that in Keras or TensorFlow? I know I can dump the weights of the trained neural network into a file, but that won't help as the weights are just from one node to another in the next hidden layer.

Thanks

```
Xtrain, Xtest, Ytrain, Ytest = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=.5)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu', input_dim=16))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, validation_data=(Xtest,Ytest), epochs=200, batch_size=100, verbose=1)

Ypred = model.predict(Xtest)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be a bit tricky, and I don't know how to do it in Keras, but multiplying the matrices backwards (the opposite of feedforward) from the output unit (over the range of possible outcomes) to the input units can show the pattern of input units that the network associates with each outcome. Have a look at: https://github.com/makeyourownneuralnetwork/makeyourownneuralnetwork/blob/master/part3_neural_network_mnist_backquery.ipynb.